# Calculate $(631-8)!$ modulo the prime $631$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the least residue of the (multiplicative) inverse of
(631-8)!
modulo 631. (Note that 631 is prime.)

I imagine Fermats or Wilsons will be used but I am not sure how to use either theorem in regards to this problem.

Comment: Use Wilson reflection as in the linked dupes.